# Check radio button from pageinit does not work

Tags: jquery-mobile, radio-button, page-init

The following code does not work, the radio button is not checked. Any idea why?

I've tried `attr('checked', 'checked')` as well.

```
<html>
<head>      
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>      
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).bind("pageinit", function () {           
        $('#radio-pet-2a').attr('checked', true);
    });         
    </script>
  </head>
 <body>

<div data-role="content">

    <ul data-role = "listview">

        <li>
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
        <legend>Choose a pet:</legend>
             <input type="radio" name="radio-pet" id="radio-pet-1a" value="choice-1"   />
             <label for="radio-pet-1a">Cat</label>

             <input type="radio" name="radio-pet" id="radio-pet-2a" value="choice-2"  />
             <label for="radio-pet-2a">Dog</label>

             <input type="radio" name="radio-pet" id="radio-pet-3a" value="choice-3"  />
             <label for="radio-pet-3a">Hamster</label>

             <input type="radio" name="radio-pet" id="radio-pet-4a" value="choice-4"  />
             <label for="radio-pet-4a">Lizard</label>
    </fieldset>
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out how to let it work:

```
    $(document).bind("pageinit", function () {           
        $('#radio-pet-2a').attr('checked', true);
        $("input[type='radio']").checkboxradio("refresh"); 
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the **prop** method to set attribute check of radio button and then refresh radio button.

```
$(document).bind("pageinit", function () {           
    $('#radio-pet-2a').prop("checked", true).checkboxradio("refresh");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the rendering by using `button('refresh')` after changing the logical setting:

```
$(document).bind("pageinit", function () {           
    $('#radio-pet-2a').attr('checked', true).button('refresh');
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work. The page will keep loading. I just tried it.